# Simulating accuracy according to a predictor variable? (R)

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-modeling, computational-modeling

I'm trying to illustrate a proof-of-concept by simulating some data in RStudio, but I'm not totally sure how to go about the first part of the simulation -- modelling response accuracy.

Basically: I have one predictor variable (X) that varies across 'trials', and I want simulated response accuracy to increase along side X (so that when X is very large, accuracy on that trial is very likely to = 1, but when X is very small, accuracy on that trial is very likely to = 0).

My initial thought was to generate a 'probability of correct response' variable that is positively correlated with X; then, I'd recode anything > .5 as a 1, and anything < .5 as a 0. But, I'm not totally sure if this approach is justifiable, or if there's a better way to go.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Some terms that might help you:

It's common for accuracy to follow a *[sigmoidal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)* curve; the *[logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function)* is one example.

Binary outcomes are modeled well using a *[binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)* distribution (or [Bernoulli for a single trial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution)).

So, what you likely want to do is to:

1. choose some sigmoidal function that represents "average accuracy" over your predictor variable *x*.
2. at values of x, simulate Bernoulli trials or represent multiple Bernoulli trials with a random number from the binomial distribution, using the average probability from your chosen value of *x* and function from (1).

I won't write the R code for you, but that should be enough to get you started with some search terms for example code that works towards these steps.